# Paypal Related application in j2me and symbian

Tags: java-me, symbian

I want to know that can we make paypel related application in j2me and symbian OS?
Is it secure?
If we can make such application then can i get the api used for that.

Please help me for that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether PayPal offers any SDK for using the service on said platform through library APIs, the answer is no. See https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks?bn_r=m

If you are asking whether you could implement the NVP/SOAP APIs on this platform is: you could and it could be secure. It all depends on you ;)